# Predicting millions of sparse timeseries using them to help each other

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, statistics

This is a very general problem faced by different types of businesses. Predict the future behavior of customers over time.

Imagine that we have 1 million customers with their own features over time, forming a time series. The classic approach (statistics like ARIMA, Bayesian like prophet or purely computational like LSTM) here is not very suitable as I would consider that each series team is completely independent, many series are super sparse or have just started and to treat them individually that train a model for each series.

The more conservative approach asks a first classifier to understand what is the behavior of the time series (as a kind of grouper) so we have curves with the same seasonality and trends and then normalize so that the level is the same. We train the models for each of these groups and then we go back to the old level and we have an individual forecast.

I would like to know if there is a more appropriate technique or a canonical solution for the model to understand and predict all series more accurately, using "knowledge of the group" (of the time series that are more similar) in a more scalable way.